# How to set up DNS port forwarding using xinetd?

Tags: linux, powerdns, xinetd

I have a KVM hypervisor and a few VMs in a bridged network. I use xinetd to forward ports from the public IP address to the proper VM.

Now I installed PowerDNS on a machine and I'd like to create a port forwarding rule for it. It looks like this:

```
service dns-switch
{
 disable = no
 type = UNLISTED
 socket_type = dgram
 protocol = udp
 wait = no
 redirect = 192.168.0.3 53
 bind = x.x.x.x
 port = 53
 user = nobody
}
```

After restarting xinetd I get the following message in /var/log/messages and the forwarding is not working:

```
Mar 12 15:12:57 server systemd: Starting Xinetd A Powerful Replacement For Inetd...
Mar 12 15:12:57 server xinetd[5037]: socket creation failed (Protocol not supported (errno = 93)). service = dns-switch
Mar 12 15:12:57 server xinetd[5037]: Service dns-switch failed to start and is deactivated.
Mar 12 15:12:57 server xinetd[5037]: xinetd Version 2.3.15 started with libwrap loadavg labeled-networking options compiled in.
```

Of course, nothing on netstat/ss. The host is a CentOS 7. The guest (PowerDNS) is Ubuntu 14.04.

Any idea/suggestion is welcome.

Comment: According to the man page, the UDP cannot be redirected:


    `redirect: Allows a tcp service to be redirected to another host`

Answer (score 0):

You could use dnsdist to forward your queries. It is extremely flexible but can also do this simple forwarding case.

Comment: I've never used it, but it looks simple to set up. I'll give it a try. Thank you!